# Program to input string and print it back won't work

Tags: printing, lisp, common-lisp

I have what I feel should be a very simple bit of code in Common Lisp, all I want it to do is ask for an input from the user, then print it back.

This is my code (The "Before" and "After" printing is from trying to debug, and it showed something odd.

```
(defun get-input (prompt)
    (clear-input)
    (write-string prompt)
    (finish-output)
    (read-line)
)

(let    (   
            (p1 (get-input "Enter: "))
        )
    (princ "Before")
    (princ p1)
    (princ "After")
)
```

When I run this I get the following

```
This is SBCL 1.2.1, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.

WARNING: the Windows port is fragile, particularly for multithreaded
code.  Unfortunately, the development team currently lacks the time
and resources this platform demands.
* (load "test.lisp")

Enter: This is my string.
AftereThis is my string.
T
```

As you can see, my "Before" string isn't even printed, and my "After" string has a strange "e" on the end? And why is it seemingly asking for input when I first run the program?

If anyone could help I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: what does the tag 'clisp' mean? CLISP is a specific Common Lisp implementation. The prompt in your example is not from CLISP...

Comment: @RainerJoswig edited it out.

Comment: If `Before`were printed, and then `After` were printed on top, you'd see  `Aftere`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what is happening, in order:

1. The program evaluates the expression to be bound to `p1`; this generates your prompt & reads your input
2. *Then* it prints "Before"
3. Then it prints the value of `p1`, which (I think) has a carriage return at the end, so that the next thing to be printed goes at the start of the line
4. Then it prints "After", overwriting the first 5 characters of "Before"

Comment: That makes sense, do you know how I might fix it?

Comment: @sam, although I cannot reproduce this behavior, I think Scott Hunter's assumption may be true. So you can try this: `(princ (string-right-trim "#\newline" p1))`.

Comment: I think that trimming might solve the immediate problem, but the underlying problem is that your input ends with CR-LF, but gets treated as if it had only LF as a line terminator, stripping only that.  I guess that this could be caused by some shell or readline library wrapping your REPL prompt.  You would have to properly configure that.

Answer (score 0):

**Additional Information from sam: SBCL under Windows.**

Well, yeah. SBCL's port to Windows is very rough.

See the warning in your output:

> WARNING: the Windows port is fragile, particularly for multithreaded
>   code.  Unfortunately, the development team currently lacks the time
>   and resources this platform demands.

SBCL comes from the Linux/Unix/... world. The port to Windows makes assumptions which are valid for Linux/Unix/... but not for Windows.

One thing is line termination. Windows uses CRLF. Unix uses LF. SBCL under Windows uses LF, IIRC. Probably this can be configured somehow.

If you now use a shell under Windows which expects CRLF conventions and create direct output with SBCL using LF conventions, then you may get strange output...

**Thus possible *solutions* are:**

- use a Lisp which support Windows conventions. Problem: there are not many. There are really good ones like LispWorks and Allegro CL, but they are relatively expensive. I don't know how Clozure CL does it - it also runs under Windows and is free...
- find out how to configure SBCL to use Windows I/O conventions. -> SBCL mailing list
- reconfigure your terminal/shell to use Unix LF conventions

**I can't reproduce that (CLISP and SBCL in a terminal on the Mac):**

**CLISP**

```
rjmba:~ joswig$ clisp
  i i i i i i i       ooooo    o        ooooooo   ooooo   ooooo
  I I I I I I I      8     8   8           8     8     o  8    8
  I  \ `+' /  I      8         8           8     8        8    8
   \  `-+-'  /       8         8           8      ooooo   8oooo
    `-__|__-'        8         8           8           8  8
        |            8     o   8           8     o     8  8
  ------+------       ooooo    8oooooo  ooo8ooo   ooooo   8

Welcome to GNU CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07) <http://clisp.cons.org/>

Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Michael Stoll 1992, 1993
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Marcus Daniels 1994-1997
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Pierpaolo Bernardi, Sam Steingold 1998
Copyright (c) Bruno Haible, Sam Steingold 1999-2000
Copyright (c) Sam Steingold, Bruno Haible 2001-2010

Type :h and hit Enter for context help.

[1]> (load "/tmp/g.lisp")
;; Loading file /tmp/g.lisp ...
Enter: hello
BeforehelloAfter
;; Loaded file /tmp/g.lisp
T
[2]> (quit)
```

**SBCL**

```
rjmba:~ joswig$ sbcl
This is SBCL 1.1.16, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (load "/tmp/g.lisp")
Enter: hello
BeforehelloAfter
T
```

You might want to tell us your specific implementation and platform combination, plus where Common Lisp does its output...

Comment: @Mark: I can't post output like that in comments. The original poster might want to show actual output like this and specify what he is using. We should not guess what he is actually using (Lisp version, platform, output display, ...). If it is CLISP version specific, he might want to ask on the CLISP mailing list.

Comment: I have now put exactly what comes up when I run my program, I am using windows. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark but maybe if the terminal is to blame you can try bash under windows. Git is distributed with it, or just install msys